# In Xamarin Forms how can I stop the keyboard from being dismissed? (Android)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have an Entry and ListView.

The Entry allows the user to filter the items in the LisView.

Each item in the ListView is selectable, which means that when the user taps on the item a check mark is added in the right.
He can select multiple items.

When the user starts typing in the Keyboard the ListView gets filtered and he can select items.

in iOS when the user selects an item the Keyboard is NOT dismissed, which is the behaviour I want.

in ANDROID when the user selects an item the Keyboard is dismissed.

How can I make Android to have the same iOS behaviour and keep the Keyboard on when tapping in the ListView items?

Thanks

Comment: Did you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/42370358/8395242

Comment: Yes I did. I think that would keep the keyboard always open. I need to keep it open only when interacting with the ListView