# Avoid keyboard hiding while navigating focus between different Entry

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I navigate focus from an `Entry` to another `Entry` inside a `AbsoluteLayout` through a button click.

On every focus navigation the keyboard hide and again comes back to visiblity. I want the Keyboard to avoid hiding if the Next child to be focused is an `Entry`.

**Xaml code**

```cs
<Grid>
    <ScrollView>
        <local:CustomLayout
            x:Name="entryStack"
            BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItems}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Entry
                        WidthRequest="100"
                        Focused="Entry_Focused"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </local:CustomLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <Button VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="End" Text="NextField" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
</Grid>
```

**`CustomLayout` inheriting `AbsoluteLayout`**

```cs
public class CustomLayout : AbsoluteLayout
{
    public CustomLayout()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnChildAdded(Element child)
    {
        base.OnChildAdded(child);
        var childElement = (child as View);
        var index = this.Children.IndexOf(childElement);
        childElement.TranslationY = index * 30;
    }
}
```

**Xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public List<string> SomeItems { get; set; }
    int i = 0;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SomeItems = new List<string>()
        {
            "One",
            "One",
            "One",
            "One",
            "One",
            "One",
            "One",
            "One",
            "One",
            "One",
            "One",
            "One",
            "One",
            "One",
        };

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        i = i+1;
        (entryStack.Children[i] as Entry).Focus();
    }

    void Entry_Focused(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        i = entryStack.Children.IndexOf((sender as Entry));
    }
}
```

[image]

Is this possible to achieve. Am I doing something wrong here??

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42384926/4550227

Comment: No @GanesanVG, I'll try now.

Comment: I tried it now, @GanesanVG. The code was not meant to keep the Keyboard open but to show the Keyboard. What I need is to avoid the closing of Keyboard while next Entry is focused

Comment: I think you need to do something in the custom renderer and have a look at [comments in this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/160532/setting-focus-from-one-entry-to-another-entry-in-code-closes-and-opens-softkeyboard-on-android) may give you some idea. I will update you if I find a solution.

Comment: Thanks @JackHua-MSFT. Will check the thread.

Comment: You should also consider the scenario that if the entries use different types of keyboard.