# How to keep soft keyboard always open in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am working in a Xamarin Forms APP, we want to go through different entries (not using TabIndex because we need a custom logic), but we want to keep the keyboard always on during looping through entries. We are using ReturnCommand to Focus the NEXT entry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep keyboard on Xamarin.Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370358/how-to-keep-keyboard-on-xamarin-forms)

Comment: No, because that works when you call .Focus from a Button or other control that fire a TouchEvent, but when you call ReturnCommand those events are not fired. I already tried. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: ok I see, have you tried to search on how to show/hide keyboard? maybe it will be helpful.

Comment: I did, hiding or showing it is not the problem, problem is to avoid hiding due to lost focus or ReturnCommand finished or clicking in any part of the screen. I want to control by code when to show it and when to hide it.

Comment: This is contrary to the design, the soft keyboard pop-up prerequisite is that the control is in focus.There is a workaround below (for android,that will keep an Entry in focus and keep the keyboard displayed).

Answer (score 1):

Create a **CustomEntryRenderer** in your Android project :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace your namespace
class CustomEntryRenderer:EntryRenderer
{
    public CustomEntryRenderer(Context context):base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }

}
```

and add this in your MainActivity:

```
 private bool _lieAboutCurrentFocus;
 public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        var focused = CurrentFocus;
        bool customEntryRendererFocused = focused != null && focused.Parent is CustomEntryRenderer;

        _lieAboutCurrentFocus = customEntryRendererFocused;
        var result = base.DispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        _lieAboutCurrentFocus = false;

        return result;
    }

    public override Android.Views.View CurrentFocus
    {
        get
        {
            if (_lieAboutCurrentFocus)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return base.CurrentFocus;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works only when you raise touch events, but if you call .Focus() from a ReturnCommand it does not works.

Comment: If you set `ReturnType="Next"` to Entry,you don't need to call `.Focus()` method to focus the next entry in `ReturnCommand`.

Comment: ReturnType="Next" will go to the next entry using TabIndex, but I have a custom selection login in the ReturnCommand, so I choose the following entry evaluating different properties a then once I found the Entry that I want I call .Focus() and also make it visible because it is inside a ListView.

Comment: It's against the design if you want to lose focus and display the keyboard.