# Can I force the soft keyboard to open when a device has a hard keyboard in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

I am trying to force the soft keyboard to open when a text entry is on focus, and when the Android device already has a hard keyboard?

According to [this website](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility), the following approach won't work (I also tried it out).

```
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" ... >
    ...
</activity>
```

I have also tried using `InputMethodManager.ShowSoftInput()` with no success. I found this approach [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/584f1472-0840-4044-a6c4-ca50ecc072c3/how-to-show-the-soft-keyboard-when-activity-opens?forum=xamarinandroid).

Can anyone help further? Maybe the flags of `ShowSoftInput` need some particular values? Thanks a lot

Comment: Do any of the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42370358/199364) help? Or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64653114/199364)?

Comment: You can try to set the input way as soft keyboard by the Language&Input  in the Settings.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve kind of yes, thank you! I used inputMethodManager.ShowSoftInput() and it works. If anyone sees this, be careful with the flag parameter, it can lead to nasty unstableness.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT ironically, this also helped. Setting the virtual keyboard to be on from the device settings can avoid all the programmatic approach. Thank you