# Prevent lost focus tapping outside Entry in Xamarin Forms

Tags: forms, xamarin, controls, focus

I have an entry and an Image which can be zoomed an panned by some gesture listeners. The user should be able to tap into the entry and write down some text that is on the image. While the entry is focused the user should also zoom and pan the image to any position to better read the text in the image - the focus of the entry shouldn't get lost while zooming and panning and the soft keyboard should stay in front.

Is it possible to set any property of the image to dismiss focus on this and retain focus on the entry? It has to work for both Android and iOS.

Here is some XAML code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Entry Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Value}" />
    <views:PinchToZoomContainer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
        <Image HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" Source="testimage.jpg" WidthRequest="100" />
    </views:PinchToZoomContainer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi, could you share some code or screenshot to explain that? It will be better to check that.

Comment: It's a very generic thing but I have added some XAML code to my question.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I have found a similar discussion, you could have a try. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370358/how-to-keep-keyboard-on-xamarin-forms