# How to fixed the Editor element in xamarin?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing my messenger using `Xamarin Frorms`. I have a page where users communicate. Here it is.
[image: Close Editor]

My cod page XAML.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Corporate_messenger.Service"
             x:Class="Corporate_messenger.Views.CacheChatPage" Shell.BackgroundColor="#212D3B"
             Shell.TitleColor="White" x:Name="set_pqage" Shell.TabBarIsVisible="True" Title="{Binding TitlePage}" >


   
    <Shell.TitleView >
        <Grid >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />


            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TitlePage}" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Frame CornerRadius="8" HorizontalOptions="End" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5,5,5"  Padding="8" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HasShadow="True" 
       OutlineColor="Transparent"  x:Name="MyFrame">

                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" >

                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="CallTap" Tapped="CallTap_Tapped" />
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>



                    <FlexLayout 
                             Padding="3"
                        >

                        <Image Source="tCall.png" 
                               
               FlexLayout.AlignSelf="Center"
                    WidthRequest="22"   
                    HeightRequest="22"
                    >
                          
                        </Image>

                    </FlexLayout>

                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </Grid>
    </Shell.TitleView>

    <ContentPage.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>

            <DataTemplate 
            x:Key="FromTemplate">
                <ViewCell 
                x:Name="FromUserCell" 
                Tapped="FromUserCell_Tapped"
                IsEnabled="True"  >
                    <ViewCell.View >
                        <FlexLayout 
                          
                            JustifyContent="Start">

                            <Frame 
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            
                            BackgroundColor="#ECEDF1"
                            CornerRadius="14"                          
                            Padding="5,10,10,10"
                            HasShadow="false"               
                            Margin="10,10,40,10">
                               
                                <StackLayout 
                                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label 
                                        Text="{Binding Message}" 
                                        IsVisible="{ Binding IsMessageVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                                          WidthRequest="200" 
                                        IsEnabled="True"                                      
                                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"   
                                        TextColor="Black"/>
                                    <ImageButton 
                                        x:Name="LeftPlay" 
                                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyListView},Path=BindingContext.PlayAudioMessage}" 
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  
                                        Source="{Binding Path=SourceImage,Mode=TwoWay}"                                         
                                        IsVisible="{ Binding IsAuidoVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"       
                                        WidthRequest="35" HeightRequest="35" 
                                        CornerRadius="50" 
                                        BackgroundColor="#0986CE">
                                    </ImageButton>
                                    <Slider 
                                        x:Name="LeftSlider" 
                                        IsVisible="{Binding IsAuidoVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                        Maximum="{Binding MaximumSlider}" 
                                        Value="{Binding ValueSlider}"
                                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableSlider}" 
                                        MaximumTrackColor="Gray" 
                                        MinimumTrackColor="#41A9FE"                                         
                                        WidthRequest="150">
                                    </Slider>
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <Label   
                                        Text="{Binding Time_LstMessage}" 
                                        FontSize="11" MinimumWidthRequest="30" 
                                        VerticalTextAlignment="End" 
                                        HorizontalTextAlignment="End"   
                                        TextColor="DimGray"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </FlexLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>


            <DataTemplate 
                x:Key="ToTemplate">
                <ViewCell 
                    Tapped="ToUserCell_Tapped"
                    
                x:Name="ToUserCell" 
                IsEnabled="True">
                   
                       
                    
                    <FlexLayout 
                    JustifyContent="End" >
                        <Frame                      
                    CornerRadius="14" 
                    BackgroundColor="#CCE4FF"
                    Padding="5,10,10,10"
                    Margin="50,10,20,10"
                    HasShadow="false"      
                    IsClippedToBounds="True">
                            <StackLayout 
                            Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label    
                                    Text="{Binding Message}" 
                                      IsVisible="{ Binding IsMessageVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                                     WidthRequest="200" 
                                    IsEnabled="True" 
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"   
                                    TextColor="Black"/>
                                <ImageButton
                                    x:Name="RightPlay"
                                    Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyListView},Path=BindingContext.PlayAudioMessage}" 
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  
                                    Source="{Binding Path=SourceImage,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                    IsVisible="{ Binding IsAuidoVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                    WidthRequest="35" 
                                    HeightRequest="35" 
                                    CornerRadius="50" 
                                    BackgroundColor="#0986CE">
                                </ImageButton>

                                <Slider 
                                    Maximum="{Binding MaximumSlider}" 
                                    Value="{Binding ValueSlider}"                                    
                                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableSlider}"                                    
                                    IsVisible="{Binding IsAuidoVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    WidthRequest="150"  
                                    MaximumTrackColor="Gray" 
                                    MinimumTrackColor="#41A9FE">
                                </Slider>

                                <Label  
                                    Text="{Binding Time_LstMessage}" 
                                    FontSize="11" 
                                    MinimumWidthRequest="30" 
                                    VerticalTextAlignment="End" 
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="End"   
                                    TextColor="DimGray"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </FlexLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            <local:ClassDataTemplateSelector
                x:Key="chatDataTemplateSelector" 
                FromTemplate="{StaticResource FromTemplate}" 
                ToTemplate="{StaticResource ToTemplate}"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <!--Страница сообщений-->
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--Список сообщений-->
            <ListView
              
                ItemTapped="MyListView_ItemTapped"
                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                
                IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}" 
                RefreshCommand="{Binding UpdateList}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource chatDataTemplateSelector}"  
                ItemsSource="{Binding MessageList}"
                Background="#1D2733" 
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" 
                RefreshControlColor="Cyan"  
                Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                SeparatorColor="Transparent"  
                x:Name="MyListView" 
                HasUnevenRows="true" 
                >
               
            </ListView>

            <Grid 
                x:Name="GridInput"
                ColumnSpacing="0" Grid.Row="1">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!--Атрибут для написания сообщения-->
                <Editor
                    Visual="Material"
                    Text="{Binding Input_message}"  
                    Margin="5,0,0,0"  
                    x:Name="MessageEditor" 
                    Completed="MessageEditor_Completed"
                    TextChanged="MessageEditor_TextChanged"
                    Keyboard="Chat" 
                    TextColor="Black" 
                    Placeholder="Введите сообщение..." 
                    
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Grid.Column="0">
                </Editor>

                <!--Кнопка отправить сообщение-->
                <ImageButton
                    Command="{Binding SendMessage}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                    Clicked="send_message_Clicked"
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Grid.Column="1" 
                    Source="send_msg.png" 
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                    WidthRequest="32" HeightRequest="32" 
                    x:Name="send_message"  
                    IsVisible="false"
                  />

                <!--Кнопка отправить голсовое сообщение-->
                <ImageButton  
                    Pressed="mic_message_Pressed" 
                    Released="mic_message_Released" 
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Grid.Column="1" 
                    Source="mic.png" 
                    Padding="0" 
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"  
                    WidthRequest="32" 
                    HeightRequest="32" 
                    x:Name="mic_message" 
                    IsVisible="true"
                    Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
            </Grid>
            <ContentView x:Name="popupLoadingView" BackgroundColor="#C0808080"  IsVisible="false"   >

                <Frame                      
                    Margin="10,0,10,10"
                    Padding="0"
                    CornerRadius="14" 
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                 
                  VerticalOptions="End"  HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    
                   >
                    <StackLayout Margin="0" Padding="0" Spacing="0"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Fill">

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="0"  x:Name="StackCopy"  BackgroundColor="White" Padding="20,20,20,20" >
                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="Copy" Tapped="Copy_Tapped"/>
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <ImageButton Source="copyText.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent" WidthRequest="32" HeightRequest="32"></ImageButton>
                            <Label Text="Cкопировать" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="Transparent" ></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="0"   BackgroundColor="White" Padding="20,20,20,20" >
                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="DeleteTap" Tapped="DeleteTap_Tapped"/>
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <ImageButton Source="deleteM.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent" WidthRequest="32" HeightRequest="32"></ImageButton>
                            <Label Text="Удалить для всех" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="Transparent" ></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
              
         
            </ContentView>
        </Grid>
       
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

When I write a message, the 'Editor' control opens. But when I click the submit button, the Editor control is hidden again. How do I make this element fixed so that the user decides when to close it.
Here is the photo where the editor is open.
[image: Open editor]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42370358/8395242

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In android, you can try the following code, it works on my side.

1.In MainActivity.cs, add following code:

```
   private bool _lieAboutCurrentFocus; 
    public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        var focused = CurrentFocus;
        bool customEntryRendererFocused = focused != null && focused.Parent is CustomEntryRenderer;

        _lieAboutCurrentFocus = customEntryRendererFocused;
        var result = base.DispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        _lieAboutCurrentFocus = false;

        return result;
    }

    public override View CurrentFocus
    {
        get
        {
            if (_lieAboutCurrentFocus)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return base.CurrentFocus;
        }
    }
```

2.create `CustomEntryRenderer.cs`  in android

```
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))] 
namespace FormApp826.Droid
{
    public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer, TextView.IOnEditorActionListener
    {

        public CustomEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            //do nothiing
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == Entry.TextProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                base.Control.Text = base.Element.Text;
                if (base.Control.IsFocused)
                {
                    base.Control.SetSelection(base.Control.Text.Length);
                }
                return;
            }
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }

    }
 }
```

3.create class `CustomEntry.cs`

```
public class CustomEntry:Entry{

}
```

4.Usage:

```
         <formapp826:CustomEntry    Placeholder="test"  HorizontalOptions="Fill"  BackgroundColor="Gray"  Margin="10"/> 

        <Button  Text="test" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
```